# How to count how many identical ligament $ key = $ val in the general array?

Tags: php

I have Array:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = array(2628927 => "8250843");
$arr[1] = array(2628927 => "8250843");
$arr[2] = array(2783907 => "8250843");
$arr[3] = array(2783907 => "8250843");
$arr[4] = array(2648250 => "8250843");
$arr[5] = array(2628927 => "8250843");

$arr1 = array();
```

unique ligament **key=> value** i get with script

```
foreach($arr as $a)
{
    if(!in_array($a, $arr1)){
        $arr1[] = $a;
    }
}
```

than i output value unique ligament **key=> value**:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $keys => $elms ) {
foreach ( $elms as $key => $val ) {
echo "$key = $val<br>";
```

**How to count how many identical ligament $ key = $ val in the general array $arr?**

```
}
}
```

*For example count for 2628927 => "8250843" will be 3*

**How get this?**

***IF YOU WANT VOTE DOWN PLEASE GIVE ANSWER.***

***BIG THANKS)***

Comment: Huh? Whatcha talkin 'bout Willis?

Comment: count($arr) - count($arr1) ?

Comment: need get count $key => $val in array $arr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your expected result is **3**, then try the below:

```
$count = count(array_unique(array_map('serialize', $arr)));
```

***Edit:***

```
function foo($arr, $target) {
  $data = array_count_values(array_map('serialize', $arr));
  $key = serialize($target);
  return isset($data[$key]) ? $data[$key] : 0;
}

$arr = array();
$arr[0] = array(2628927 => "8250843");
$arr[1] = array(2628927 => "8250843");
$arr[2] = array(2783907 => "8250843");
$arr[3] = array(2783907 => "8250843");
$arr[4] = array(2648250 => "8250843");
$arr[5] = array(2628927 => "8250843");

echo foo($arr, array(2628927 => "8250843")); // the result is 3
```

Comment: If it so - then I wonder why question isn't titled "How to count how many **different** ..."

Comment: @zerkms no) for example count for 2628927 => "8250843" will be 3

Comment: @LeoLoki You question is not clear at first, I updated my answer, which should give you the expected result.